# Groovy Script in soapUI: Cannot execute the conditional statement while the condition is true

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm facing a problem in my groovy script

I'm trying to read values from file and compare it with values from JSON object

```
//Reading Ids from the Payload and add it to the list
def jsonStr = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("PayLoad")
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper();
def result = slurper.parseText(jsonStr)
def services = []
for(int i=0; i < result.catalog.size();i++){
        services << result.catalog[i].serviceId
        //log.info(services[i])
    }
// The Validation message 
def valmessage = "Tmam"
boolean flag = false
for(int z = 0 ; z < services.size(); z++){
    File file = new File("C://Users//ssd//Desktop//Vafdf//"+services[z]+".txt")
    def cservices = file.readLines();
    log.info("The file readed is  " + services[z]+" and the content is "+cservices[0])
for (int i =0 ; i< cservices.size();i++){
        for(int j =0 ; j <services.size();j++){
            log.info("      "+cservices[i]+"   "+services[j])
                if (cservices[i].equals(services[j])){
                flag = true
                //log.info("Service "+services[z]+" is contradicting with "+services[j])
                log.info("I am the IF condition")
                break
                }
            }
    }}
    if (flag == true){
        if (valmessage == "Error"){
                assert true
            }else assert false
        }else if (flag == false)
        {
            if (valmessage == "Tmam"){
                assert true
                }else assert false
            }
```

The "If" condition never executes however the logs shows that the compared values are equals

```
log.info("      "+cservices[i]+"   "+services[j])
    if (cservices[i].equals(services[j])){
                        flag = true
                        //log.info("Service "+services[z]+" is contradicting with "+services[j])
                        log.info("I am the IF condition")
                        break
                        }
```

here is the output

```
Thu Jul 19 18:43:48 EET 2018:INFO:The file readed is  1 and the content is 2
Thu Jul 19 18:43:48 EET 2018:INFO:      2   1
Thu Jul 19 18:43:48 EET 2018:INFO:      2   2
Thu Jul 19 18:43:48 EET 2018:INFO:The file readed is  2 and the content is 1
Thu Jul 19 18:43:48 EET 2018:INFO:      1   1
Thu Jul 19 18:43:48 EET 2018:INFO:      1   2
```

Comment: Can you convert it .toString() before comparsion. Also to simplify remove loops and check you can just check with some static values like  if (cservices[2].equals(services[2]) and check if it goes inside. .toString can help.. also try to use ==

Comment: Also check in case there are any spaces in that where you are printing log.info

Comment: indeed, it may be a problem of types, to check the variables types you could do log.info cservices[i].getClass() and log.inof services[j].getClass() to check if they are the same ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved
The problem was "result.catalog[i].serviceId" is not considered as string and just when I put it in the string variable or just concatenate it with   +""  it worked